# I can not access to share folder

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, authentication, iis-6, administration

I need to temporarily access the network to separate directories.
When do it I have access exception.
I'm from Ukraine. not sure about the accuracy of the translation.
**"Logon not produced: Username or password not recognized"**

access from my PC to the share directory I have **>> Start >> Run >> \\network addres**

Comment: check the account unter which your `AppPool` is running, and also any impersonation settings on your site. Debug and check the Identity/Credentials your code is using has the access to shared folder.

Comment: I also thought about it. how to look from a user's query is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access any shared folder from your application you need to make `Virtual Directory` of that Folder

Comment: you right. thank. you realy help me))